# How to reset grid row height after using splitter?

Tags: wpf

With the following XAML the bottom row hides when you uncheck the checkbox. Everything is well until you resize it with the gridsplitter. Then checking/unchecking the checkbox doesn't do anything. Given that the converter sets the Height to 0 I expected the row to hide. What's going on? How can I reset the heights after moving the splitter?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <m:CheckedToLengthConverter x:Key="checkedToLengthConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ElementName=ShowBottomCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource checkedToLengthConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Blue" />
    <CheckBox Name="ShowBottomCheckBox" IsChecked="True" />
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="5" />
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
public class CheckedToLengthConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return new GridLength(int.Parse(parameter.ToString()), GridUnitType.Star);

        return new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that once you move the splitter the first row will have an explicit width, so setting the last row back to * won't have any effect.  After some experimentation I came up with the code below.  Note that you need to specify a TwoWay binding or it won't work.

```
public class CheckedToLengthConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public GridLength TrueValue { get; set; }
    public GridLength FalseValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    #region Overrides of MarkupExtension

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <m:CheckedToLengthConverter TrueValue="2*" FalseValue="*" x:Key="c1" />
        <m:CheckedToLengthConverter TrueValue="3*" FalseValue="0" x:Key="c2" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, 
                       ElementName=ShowBottomCheckBox, 
                       Converter={StaticResource c1}}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsChecked, 
                       ElementName=ShowBottomCheckBox, 
                       Converter={StaticResource c2}}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Blue" />
    <CheckBox Name="ShowBottomCheckBox" IsChecked="True" />
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="5" 
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is UX problem guys, not the code. What you trying to do makes little sense, have u tried using Visual States instead?